# Ctrl+Z in Viewport triggers compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, shortcut

I have noticed that when I edit something in the viewport, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (still in the viewport) the compositor (open in new region) will still update like I edited a node or had hovered over the compositor node setup while performing the key command. Is this a known issue, or is it a bug?

Do any of you have the same issue?

I am using Blender 2.74

Comment: What is ctrl + Z supposed to do? Are you trying to activate rendered view, because that's shift + Z.

Comment: Ctrl+Z is undo . . .

Comment: How... did I not remember that... Wow. What an absolute epic fail! It's just- so universal. Well, I can't help you now. Yes. It doesn't happen for me, but it is probably a bug. Sorry about that derposity. :3

Comment: I think that the overhead of checking if undoing something actually affects the compositor is quite big, so it's easier to just update it

Comment: 2.73 might work fine.. also make sure it is specifically blender that has the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is the shortcut for undo, if you have global undo enabled in preferences (which is enabled by default) then the undo stack can contain steps from multiple windows, this means that undo may change the node editor if you made a change there before going to the 3dview and doing undo.

Comment: Ah, I see. The undo stack is global, not for each region. Is there a way to change that? I guess probably not without forking Blender

Comment: You can turn off the global undo in preferences under editing, but you may find that non-global undo doesn't work as well.